# Show embedded Google Map using PlaceId

Tags: google-maps

I really like the embedded google maps, it's much nicer for the users than what you get with the Javascript API.

However, I would like to be sure I always refer a user to the same place. Right now I'm using lat/long, but it would be better to use PlaceIds.

Thing is, I can't find a way to specify the location by PlaceId. Is that possible?

For example, simply searching for the PlaceId `ChIJ7y3gZVfLHkcRsicTw64FU3w` in Google Maps doesn't work. Adding `id:`, `place:`, `placeId:` prefixes has no effect either.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As far as I can determine, you can't search by placeId on the regular google maps, but the embed version [does allow it](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide#place_mode), by prefixing the placeId with `place_id:` in the search.

So an example embed would be:

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place
    ?key=YOUR_API_KEY
    &q=place_id:ChIJs--MqP1YwokRBwAhjXWIHn8"></iframe>
```

Place Ids can be found with [this tool](https://developers.google.com/places/place-id#find-id).

Comment: Thank you!! This works!! Better than the official docs!!